# SLF4J issues when creating a new SpringBoot project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, slf4j

I know there is a lot of post talking about SLF4J issues, but none of them helped me to resolve my issue.

I have created a new project with [Spring Initializer](https://start.spring.io/) with the dependencies `mongoDB`, `web` and `rest` and imported files downloaded into a new IntelliJ project as a module.

I can do `mvn clean install` and it works. But here is the error message I got when I'm running the main class :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA.app/Contents/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/matteweon/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.11/logback-classic-1.1.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

And here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>poc.local</groupId>
    <artifactId>robot-shop-store</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>robot-shop-store</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.10.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <!--exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
            <!--exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I tried to add some exclusions (you can see comments in this file) to slf4j under the mongodb and data-rest dependency, and the error changed for another :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA.app/Contents/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml: org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: /Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA.app/Contents/lib/ go to this path and remove this slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar

Comment: https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation. follow explanation.

Comment: I removed all my exclusions and added      `<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId><artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>` under mongodb dependency and it works, but now it tells me that log4j is not initialized

Comment: please add informations about current issues as an edit to your question. Perhaps you have to create a log4j configuration file.

Comment: I don't think that log4j was the issue I have to solve, because I opened an older project made with the same dependencies and the project was working fine. I solved this this morning by deleting the module on IntelliJ and reimporting it again.. maybe it was a IntelliJ config error somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tried to run another projet I've done with the same dependencies and it works just fine, so I knew it wasn't the project that cause the issue, but IntelliJ itself. So I deleted my module on IntelliJ and IntelliJ's config files (.iml file and .idea folder), I reimported the project and now it's working

Answer (score -1):

I did lot of changes to my pom.xml file like exclution to slf4j but nothing worked.Finally resolved the issue by deleting slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar.This should resolve your issue.

> Jar Path:
>   file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA.app/Contents/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar